# Set value of record field to calculation involving another field in same record

Tags: haskell

How to calculate a derived value based on another field in the same
record, in this case the zoinx field? Obviously this doesn't compile and so it calls for a different design. How do you approach this?

```
  module Main where

  data Foo = Foo
    { batz  :: Double
    , zoinx :: Double
    } deriving (Show)


  foo =
    Foo 
      { batz = 1.0
      , zoinx = batz * 2
      }

  main :: IO ()
  main = do
    print foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to `RecordWildCards`, you can use `NamedFieldPuns` to list the fields explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

foo = Foo { batz, zoinx }
  where
    batz = 1.0
    zoinx = batz * 2
```

This is syntactic sugar for:

```
foo = Foo { batz = batz, zoinx = zoinx }
--          (1)    (2)   (3)     (4)
  where
    batz = 1.0
    zoinx = batz * 2
```

(1) and (3) refer to the fields of `Foo` while (2) and (4) refer to the bindings in the `where` clause.

I find this more readable because it’s clearer which names come from where, and it’s more resilient to changes in the code—in particular: which names are in scope, and the names of the fields of the data type.

`NamedFieldPuns` can also be used similarly in patterns:

```
let Foo { batz, zoinx } = foo in batz + zoinx

case foo of { Foo { batz, zoinx } -> batz + zoinx }
```

Likewise these are syntactic sugar for:

```
let Foo { batz = batz, zoinx = zoinx } = foo in batz + zoinx

case foo of { Foo { batz = batz, zoinx = zoinx } -> batz + zoinx }
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Do you ever prefer the desugared version? I only ask because I see there are caveats with both RecordWildCards and NamedFieldPuns, for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/aq961k/recordwildcards_no_namedfieldpuns_also_no_maybe_eh/

Comment: @Joe Yeah, by default I use no record-related extensions, so I’d write something like `Foo { batz = b, zoinx = z }`, or use accessor functions or lenses. I typically only reach for `NamedFieldPuns` when dealing with large records, and even then confine the scope as much as possible, within a short `case` branch or `let`…`in`… expression. It’s a matter of style and the tradeoffs between writability and readability, but I tend to err on the side of the latter, and often that means spending a bit more time and code to be explicit, for instance, using `qualified` or named imports.

Comment: @Joe Indeed you can also use accessor functions here: `foo = Foo { batz = 1.0, zoinx = batz foo * 2 }` or `foo = fix $ \ self -> Foo { batz = 1.0, zoinx = batz self * 2 }` (`$` omittable with `BlockArguments`)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is [`RecordWildCards` extension](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#record-wildcards):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

foo = Foo {..}
  where
    batz = 1.0
    zoinx = batz * 2
```

Comment: I see there are some caveats and mixed opinions on RecordWildCards extension because if not used carefully it can cause you to lose type checking (and other negatives). However, I found a nice blog post discussing tradeoffs and design considerations: https://kodimensional.dev/recordwildcards

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what the general intention is here. Obviously, you could define this value simply as:

```
foo =
  Foo 
    { batz = 1.0
    , zoinx = 2.0
    }
```

but I'm sure you don't need to be told that, and it's probably not at all helpful.

If you want to be able to create several different `Foo` values each with this relation between the fields, then you could simply define a function like this:

```
makeFoo :: Double -> Foo
makeFoo x = Foo { batz = x, zoinx = 2 * x }
```

and then of course `foo = makeFoo 1`

And this could be generalised further in a few ways - firstly by changing the multiplier:

```
makeFoo2 :: Int -> Double -> Foo
makeFoo2 n x = Foo { batz = x, zoinx = n * x }
```

or you could indeed use an arbitrary function:

```
makeFoo3 :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> Foo
makeFoo3 f x = Foo { batz = x, zoinx = f x }
```

Hopefully these solutions can meet whatever real life situation inspired this question.